# Tabbar vanishes - How can I force it to stay?

Tags: ios, tableview, tabbar

I finally implemented a tabbar (took me way longer than I thought) in my program. Problem is that it vanishes as soon as the user clicks on a button in a view. I know that the navigation should be done by the tabbar, I still need the user to click the button to save data. You might say I could just let him save the data and then let him click on his own the tabbar to see what he entered. But no, I want him to be able to get to the view, while the tabbar stays active. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

This happens when the user taps button:

```
(button.tag = 9001);
UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
SecondView *second =[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
second.buttonTag  = buttonPressed.tag;
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

I forgot to mention: Because I need the coredata and stuff I didn't make a tabbar application but added the tabbar later on (just now to be exact). I did it like SEG described in his answer -> [steps to add tabbarcontroller to AppDelegate using Interface Builder in XCode 4.2 Empty Application template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201207/steps-to-add-tabbarcontroller-to-appdelegate-using-interface-builder-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Post the code that gets executed when the user taps the save button.

Comment: I edited and updated it!

Comment: Is it that your modal view presentation occupies the whole screen on your device(I am thinking its an iPhone)?

Comment: Well as soon as it changes to the other viewcontroller, yes. (Correct its an iPhone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presentModalViewController shows the new view controller covering up the navigation bar. Not sure what you UI needs to be for this case, but you could show the new view controller using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

Then when you are ready to close the view

```
[self.navigationController popViewController:YES];
```

to get back to the first view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what's weird though, it doesnt work. But I might now why, I edited my first post so you can see, how I added the Tabbar.